# Dynamic 1 or 2 column layout with float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a problem and I can't figure it out.

I have two divs: sidebar (30%) and content (70%).

My HTML and CSS looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
width: 100%
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Depending on the content or let's say the page, #sidebar is not included. In those cases I want #content to fill 100% and not 70%.

Is there a way to realize that?

Thanks!

Comment: in what case would the sidebar not be needed

Comment: It will be far easier to use server-side code to add a class like 'no-sidebar' to your body tag (or even add it manually if you're writing plain HTML) and write styles based on that.  There's no reliable way to do it without one of those two approaches.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the page-classes according to your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only pure CSS solution I see would be if you're using different viewports.  If you don't want to see the sidebar on mobile, for instance, set up a second stylesheet with

```
#content{width:100%}
#sidebar{display:none}
```

Otherwise integrate the alternate CSS into whatever server-side system you're using, or suppress it in the header if you need to using `<style>` tags.

Comment: Ok, I used your second suggestion, just like Dan already suggested